# Getting Code from Later On in the Page

Tags: php, javascript

I have a dynamic page which produces a variable in the content that I want to insert into the page's header.

What's the best way to fetch this variable from the page content and put it into the header? I'd prefer a PHP solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Which header do you mean? The `<head>` section, or the page's visual header? If the latter, why not just insert it into the HTML?

Comment: The <head> section, not the HTTP header or the designed header of the page.

Comment: The best thing would be to change your page's architecture so you have the variable ready when the `<head>` section is being output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is dependent on client side information you'll have to capture that info and work with it in php. Unfortunately that means that you can't have a pure PHP solution, you'll have to have something on the client side (javascript: get/post).

If your variable client side independent, then potentially you can have it calculated prior to page load and use php to put it everywhere you like.

However, if you want to do this without reloading the page then php isn't an option you'll have to use javascript/AJAX to grab the variable from the body and move it to the header.

Comment: Basically it's a variable I define server side based on information pulled from a database and then manipulated.

I then want to stuff it into the <head> section of that same page to have it serve as meta information. 

I have hoping for a pure PHP solution since I'm very weak in JS.
Regardless a Javascript get / post is the best solution I take it?

Comment: @OrunBhuiyan: If this is true meta info for opengraph, seo etc. a JS solution wont work because the clients inspecting the page arent going to run javascript - so thats kind of a non-starter.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for mentioning that, it totally slipped my mind.

Comment: @prodigitalson is correct. But if your variable is totally server side reliant, I'm not sure I see what's blocking you from calculating it and inserting it into the header with php in the same manner that you're inserting it into the body?

Comment: @abase: i think its the fact that hes doing logic and output in the same flow so the logic that sets up the variable comes long after the `head` is output.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The page being loaded is part of a Wordpress site that accomplishes several functionalities by determining what kind of page it is and then including a series of other files.

For one particular kind of page I want to inject a variable that's loaded way later in the page in header.php.

So I was thinking that the only way to do this is to identify the page right in the header and conditionally re-do the logic I'm looking for right inside the <head>. Does that sound like sound logic to you guys?

Comment: Yes, this is where @prodigitalson's advice is coming from. You'll need to re-organize your workflow so that you are identifying all the resources you need before you start outputting the page, that way when you get to the header you'll have the variable ready to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to do some serious reorganizing but that seems like the best (if not the only) way.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in php then the best answer is to separate your logic (what generates the variables value) and your view rendering (what prints out all the html) this way all the variables are prepared before you ever output anything thus you can use that same variable in multiple places.